# How to render page at a scrolled position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, anchor

I am trying to link to a page at an anchor point, i.e.:

```
<a href="/about/#content/">About</a>

<div id="content">…</div>
```

The normal browser behavior is to render the page, then jump to the anchor/ID. Is there a way to position the page at the anchor position *before* the page renders?

I've tried using

```
$(document).scrollTop( $('#content').offset().top );
```

thinking it might move to position quick enough to prevent a flash of the full page load but it doesn't work until DOM ready, so it's not quick enough.

I can cobble together a work-around by selectively hiding elements, moving to position, then showing them, but I'm wondering if there's an approach I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any other direct way of doing it. You can only guarantee faster link to a particular div making the div available as soon as possible in the DOM.

You can do this by loading the required div to be linked statically while loading the contents of other div dynamically. Again while doing this you have to make sure that the page is always scrolled to this div, by executing the code

```
$(document).scrollTop( $('#content').offset().top );
```

periodically, as when the other contents of the page are getting loaded dynamically page size may tend to increase and we would want to keep the scroll position always on the content div.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I experimented with loading other elements dynamically but it actually makes more page jumps if multiple scrollTop commands are needed. So far it's working better to load everything, hide the elements not scrolled and reveal them all once the page has loaded in the position.